# How to select multiple children from HTML tag with Python/BeautifulSoup if exists?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping elements from a webpage. Let's say i'm iterating over a HTML reponse and a part of that response looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
<div class="material">
<div class="material-parts">
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-4 2435">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt4.png"/> </span>
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-6 2631">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt6.png"/> </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I know I can access the first element under `title` within the `span` class like so:

```
row[-1].find('span')['title']
"SLT-4 2435
```

But I would like to select the second `title` under the `span` class (if it exists) as a string too, like so: `"SLT-4 2435, SLT-6 2631"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find_all()` function to find all the `span` elements with class `material-part`

```
titles = []
for material_part in row[-1].find_all('span', class_='material-part'):
    titles.append(material_part['title'])
result = ', '.join(titles)
```

Answer (score 1):

In alternativ to `find()` / `find_all()` you could use [`css selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
soup.select('span.material-part[title]')
```

,iterate the `ResultSet` with `list comprehension` and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) your texts to a single string:

```
','.join([t.get('title') for t in soup.select('span.material-part[title]')])
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
<div class="material">
<div class="material-parts">
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-4 2435">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt4.png"/> </span>
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-6 2631">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt6.png"/> </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

','.join([t.get('title') for t in soup.select('span.material-part[title]')])
```

##### Output

```
SLT-4 2435,SLT-6 2631
```